# Calculate the $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ rotations from one vector to another

Tags: vectors, rotations

If I have a $3$ vectors representing the $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ Axis of an object how would I calculate the rotations needed to get to that point from its original position of 
\begin{align}
\text{$X$-axis Vector} &= {1,0,0} \\
\text{$Y$-axis Vector} &= {0,1,0} \\
\text{$Z$-axis Vector} &= {0,0,1}
\end{align}
By the rotations needed I mean the individual rotations around the $X$, $Y$ and $Z$-axis.

Comment: @mvw I know for a fact that the only change between the 3 vectors are rotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the three vectors be $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ then we need to find the transformation matrix $T$ with
$$
b_i = T e_i \quad (i \in \{1,2,3\})
$$
This leads to a matrix equation
$$
B = T I
$$
where $B = (b_1, b_2, b_3)$ consisting of column vectors $b_i$ and $I$ is the identity matrix.
This reduces to 
$$
T = B
$$
If $T$ is the matrix of a rotation the property
$$
\mbox{det } T = 1
$$
is required. As $T=B$ this depends on the given $B$ and will not always be true for arbitrary $b_i$.

Comment: To clarify by the rotations around the X Y and Z axis the major thing I need is to calculate the angles of rotation around each of those 3 axis

Comment: That problem has many solutions. Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davenport_chained_rotations).